# BASH script: given the user input perform normalization on TSV file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, input, awk

I want to write a dynamic BASH script that would take the user input from the command line and perform normalization on the TSV file provided.

Example of TSV input:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
YES    NOT    NAME,EX    LOL,OK
Y      N      NICE,ED    LOUD,ONE
YE     NO     NEED,ER    LONE,TWO
```

As input, the script would take a delimiter, column numbers (one or more than one) and the input file and allow user to replicate row for each item in a list as a column field. Example of desired TSV output:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
YES    NOT     NAME      LOL
YES    NOT     EX        OK
Y      N       NICE      LOUD
Y      N       ED        ONE
YE     NO      NEED      LONE
YE     NO      ER        TWO
```

I have tried lots of different combinations, for example this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get user input for the selected columns (starting from 1)
echo "Enter the column numbers to split (separated by spaces):"
read -ra col_nums

# Get user input for the delimiter
echo "Enter the delimiter:"
read delimiter

# Get the input file name
echo "Enter the input file name:"
read input_file

# Get the output file name
echo "Enter the output file name:"
read output_file

# Create a temporary file for storing the modified data
temp_file=$(mktemp)

# Set the field separator to the delimiter
awk -v col_nums="${col_nums[*]}" -v delimiter="$delimiter" '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t"; split(col_nums, cn, " ") }

{
 for (i in cn) {
    # Split the selected column
    split($(cn[i]), a, delimiter)

    # Loop through the split array and create the new columns
    for (j = 1; j <= length(a); j++) {
        # Print the original columns up to the selected column
        for (k = 1; k < cn[i]; k++) {
            printf("%s%s", $k, OFS)
        }

        # Print the new column
        printf("%s%s", a[j], OFS)

        # Print the original columns after the selected column
        for (k = cn[i] + 1; k <= NF; k++) {
            printf("%s%s", $k, (k == NF ? ORS : OFS))
        }
    }
}
}' "$input_file" > "$temp_file"

# Rename the temporary file to the output file name
mv "$temp_file" "$output_file"

echo "Done."
```

However, after running this as an output I get:

```
COL1     COL2    COL4     COL4
YES     NOT     LOL      LOL,OK
YES     NOT     OK       LOL,OK
Y       N       LOUD     LOUD,ONE
Y       N       ONE      LOUD,ONE
YE      NO      LONE     LONE,TWO
YE      NO      TWO      LONE,TWO
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and what would be the best approach to this problem? It is fine with me if this is solved in one-liner as well, but with that I had even less success.

If the delimiter and column number are pre-known I would know how to do this, but the problem for me is that the output is depending on user input and several columns can be provided as input.

Comment: The example input and output looks rather surprising. What should happen if one of the columns has 2 comma-separated tokens and another one has 3? What’s the exact specification? Is it guaranteed that all columns containing commas have the same number of tokens? Or are you perhaps looking for a “cartesian product” that would handle any numbers of comma-separated tokens in any column? The latter case may well be the easiest one; one can use a recursive Bash function, pass a partially filled-in TSV line and a “template” line in arrays by reference (`declare -n` etc.) and “get exponential”.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I would like for the script to handle any number of comma-separated tokens. But, I assume that the most logical thing would be that, if two columns are specified, they have same number of comma-separated tokens.

Comment: The output you say you get from the script you posted looks very different from the output I get from it when I run it with the shell variables `col_nums=( 3 4 )` and `delimiter=','`

Comment: @sasa.asa I still don’t quite get the logic: If two columns have two comma-separated tokens, does this produce 4 output lines per input line (a cartesian product) or 2 output lines per input line? Obviously the latter in your example, but that approach cannot be easily extended to a case with 3 tokens in one column and 2 tokens in another one … which was the point behind my question.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek 2 output lines per line. Yes, you are correct, your logic is correct, this would make sense only in example with the same number of tokens in the columns, so I would stick with the example where columns have same number of tokens.

Comment: @sasa.asa `output() { local IFS=$'\t'; local -n array="$1"; printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}"; }; { read -ra headers; output headers; while read -ra line; do ntokens=1; for ((token = 0; token < ntokens; ++token)); do output=(); for field in "${line[@]}"; do IFS=, read -ra tokens <<< "$field"; if ((${#tokens[@]} > ntokens)); then ((ntokens = ${#tokens[@]})); fi; ((${#tokens[@]} == 1)) && output+=("${tokens[0]}") || output+=("${tokens[token]}"); done; output output; done; done; } < /path/to/your/input/file`

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek please don't post answers in comments where they can't be up/downvoted appropriately and comments can't easily be associated with them. It looks like you're suggesting an answer so just post it as an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton My answer is so mega-ugly that I felt the need to dodge down-voting by hiding it in a comment. It does work though (for this specific case).

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

col_nums='3 4'
delimiter=','
input_file='file'
output_file='out'

awk -v col_nums="$col_nums" -v delimiter="$delimiter" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t"
        split(col_nums, cn, " ")
        for ( i in cn ) {
            split_cols[cn[i]]
        }
    }
    {
        num_parts = split($(cn[1]),tmp,delimiter)
        for ( part_nr=1; part_nr<=num_parts; part_nr++ ) {
            for ( col_nr=1; col_nr<=NF; col_nr++ ) {
                if ( col_nr in split_cols ) {
                    split($col_nr,parts,delimiter)
                    val = parts[part_nr]
                }
                else {
                    val = $col_nr
                }
                printf "%s%s", val, (col_nr<NF ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
' "$input_file" > "$output_file"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat out
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
YES     NOT     NAME    LOL
YES     NOT     EX      OK
Y       N       NICE    LOUD
Y       N       ED      ONE
YE      NO      NEED    LONE
YE      NO      ER      TWO
```

The above assumes that, as you said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042672/bash-script-given-the-user-input-perform-normalization-on-tsv-file?noredirect=1#comment134113700_76042672):

> if two columns are specified, they have same number of comma-separated
> tokens.

Obviously, write whatever shell code you like to read/populate `col_nums`, etc. from user input.

I changed the shell variable `col_nums` from an array to a scalar above as there's no reason for it to be an array in that code.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!!! I understand your code and I can see now what went wrong with my script. This is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -r csv -r json -e '
opts=JSON.parse(File.open(ARGV[0]).read)
cols=opts["cols"]
delim=opts["delimiter"]
inp=CSV.read(ARGV[1], **{headers:false, col_sep:"\t"})

puts CSV.generate(**{headers:false, col_sep:"\t"}){|csv| 
    inp.each{|row| 
    row=[row]
    while row[-1].select.
            with_index{|e, i| cols.include?(i)}.any?{|s| s.include?(delim)} do
        row<<row[-1]
        row[-2]=row[-2].map.with_index{|s,i| 
            if cols.include?(i) then s.split(delim,2)[0] else s end}
        row[-1]=row[-1].map.with_index{|s,i| 
            if s[/,/] && cols.include?(i) then s.split(delim, 2)[1] else s end }
    end
    row.each{|sa| csv<<sa }    
    }    
}' <(echo '{"cols":[2,3],"delimiter":","}') your_file
```

Prints this TSV output:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
YES NOT NAME    LOL
YES NOT EX  OK
Y   N   NICE    LOUD
Y   N   ED  ONE
YE  NO  NEED    LONE
YE  NO  ER  TWO
```

Use JSON to send the configuration (which is self explanatory I think) and use your shell script to populate that trivial JSON line:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the column numbers to split (separated by commas):"
read col_nums

# Get user input for the delimiter
echo "Enter the delimiter:"
read delimiter

opts=$(printf "{\"cols\":[%s], \"delimiter\":\"%s\"}\n" "$col_nums" "$delimiter") 
# opts = '{"cols":[2,3], "delimiter":","}'
```

---

If you want a *table* (where the columns line up) vs *TSV*, use `column -t` in a pipe on the TSV output:

```
ruby [that ruby] <(echo "$opts") your_file | column -t
```

Prints:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
YES   NOT   NAME  LOL
YES   NOT   EX    OK
Y     N     NICE  LOUD
Y     N     ED    ONE
YE    NO    NEED  LONE
YE    NO    ER    TWO
```

The advantage here is the Ruby version is much better support for compliant CSV / TSV input and output including quoted fields, dates, and conversions.